# Tool that provides Alternate Results for Gesture Typing

Tags: gesture-typing

My problem:
I was at an event the other day taking notes on my Google Pixel 5. I had to gesture type quickly, creating 3 pages of notes. Now, a few days later, I'm reviewing my notes and correcting a few typos that unsurprisingly resulted from gesture typing. There's one particular typo, though, that I can't figure out from the context. For reference, and as an example, the typo in my notes is the word "faint".

What I've tried:
I tried gesture typing the typo word in a document just to see what other suggestions I would be given. It wasn't a success.
I looked at a physical keyboard, listed all the letters near every letter of the word "faint", and tried to determine other possible words from that swipe pattern. I'm not too great at word puzzles like that, and don't really have time to figure out every possibility, so no success there.

My question:
Are there any online or other tools available where I could type in a word and get a list of all possible gesture typing words that might be connected to that gesture (or a similar gesture)?